# Tire search return terms by first letter

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I'm using Tire/ElasticSearch to create an alphabetical browse of all the tags in my database. However, the tire search returns the tag I want *as well as* all the other tags associated to the same item. So, for example, if my letter was "A" and an item had the tags 'aardvark' and 'biscuit', both 'aardvark' and 'biscuit' would show up as results for the 'A' query. How can I construct this so that I only get 'aardvark'?

```
 def explore
 #get alphabetical tire results with term and count only

    my_letter = "A"

    self.search_result = Tire.search index_name, 'tags' => 'count' do 
      query {string 'tags:' + my_letter + '*'}
        facet 'tags' do
          terms 'tags', :order => 'term'
      end

    end.results  
  end
```

Mapping:

```
{
    items: {
        item: {
            properties: {
                tags: {
                    type: "string",
                    index_name: "tag",
                    index: "not_analyzed",
                    omit_norms: true,
                    index_options: "docs"
                  },
              }
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Can you post your mappings for **item** and **tags**? Also, can you specify what exactly do you want? I mean, do you want the item and its tags both, or are u find with tags only?

Comment: I just want the list of tags and a count. So, if you click the A link, you get all the tags that begin with A and the number of times each tag appears in the database. Click the B tag you get all the tags that begin with B, and so on. I've edited my post to include a mapping.

Answer (score 2):

Following things that you'll need to change:

1. **Mapping**
   You need to map the tags properly in order to search through them. And as your tags, are inside you item document, you need to set the properties of tags as nested, so that you can apply your search query in the facets too. Here is the mapping that you need to set:

   ```
   {
     item: {
       items: {
         properties: {
           tags: {
             properties: {
                type: "nested",
                properties: {
                   value: {
                   type: "string",
                   analyzer: 'not_analyzed'
                   }
                }
             }
          }
        }
      }
     }
   }
   ```
2. **Query**
   Now, you can use prefix query to search through the tags that start with a certain letter and get the facets, Here is the complete query:

   ```
   query: {
     nested: {
       path: "tags",
       query: {
         prefix: {
           'tags.value' : 'A'
         }
       }
     }
   }
   facets: {
     words: {
       terms: {field: 'tags.value'},
       type: 'nested',
       facet_filter: {prefix: {
                                'tags.value' : 'A'
                              }
                      }
     }
   }
   ```

Facet filter is applied while computing facets, so you'll only get the facets which will match your criteria. I preferred prefix query over regular exp. query because of performance issues. But I am not quite sure whether prefix query works for your problem. Let me know it it doesn't work.